# Take all number between tags - regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the XML:

```
<item id="232">
 <id>1</id>
</item>
```

and i made something like:

```
preg_match_all("/<item id=\"(.*)\">(.*?)<\/item>/",$content,$rss);
```

But for some reason he doesn't take all the xml only the first one.

how can I take what is between the item tags?

thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser, A.K.A., the right tool for the job?

Comment: cf. [regex match open tags except xhtml self contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content = '<item id="232">
 <id>1</id>
</item><item id="34">
 <id>23</id>
</item><item id="2234">
 <id>2342</id>
</item>';

preg_match_all('#<item id="(.*?)">(.*?)</item>#s', $content, $rss, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

`$rss[1]` will contain all the matches inside `id="..."`, whereas `$rss[2]` will contain all the matches inside `<item>...</item>`.

What matters here is the `s` modifier which will match any character including new lines. Read [PCRE Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for an explanation of this modifier and others, which are used in PHP.

Comment: ok I got it, but if I want that $rss[1] will be the content of <item> </item> because the id is not metter? I want ignore the ID..?

Comment: @John: You don't need the ID at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in actually parsing/validating the XML structure, don't bother matching the close tags:

```
preg_match_all("/<item id=\"(.*)\">/",$content,$rss);
```

If you *do* need to make sure the tags are balanced, Regular Expressions are not the right tool. Use an XML parser.

Comment: I want to take the content between the tags.. between the <item id="4324"> to </item>